# Is it possible to integrate Lua to C# and develop for windows phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, lua

I have an ios app needs to migrate to windows phone 7.
The app was created using objc and Lua.
Is it possible to integrate Lua to C# in and develop for windows phone7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of you best shots is to use a LUA implementation that targets .Net, like [LUA.Net](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/luanet/) or [LUA2IL](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/post/7).

However I'm not sure about the maturity of those implementations, and whether they are mature enough or up to date. You will need to investigate this.

If that does not work, you're left with choosing another scripting engine for your game. Best options in my book would be Boo, F#, IronPython, IronRuby or even C#.